# Give an example of a subgroup of order $9$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3 + \mathbb{Z}_3 +\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm struggling to find an example for this.

Comment: What subgroups does the group have? Try listing some.

Comment: There is a trivial subgroup and 13 subgroups of order 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider elements of the form $(a,b,0)$, there are $9$ of them and they form a subgroup.